# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: instagram

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

when i pass any special character in Recent function of instasharp.dll

InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags.Authenticated searchTags = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags.Authenticated(config, authInfo);
MediasResponse tagMediaResponses = searchTags.Recent(("@fifa"));

Comment: Got the same error. Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace ("@fifa"); with your user ID.

To get your ID
http://www.otzberg.net/iguserid/index.php